# How do I link two fields in a form so that when one field is filled out, the other autopopulates based on another list?

Tags: list, lookup-column, form

I have a form 
[image: form]
that is looking up a list [image: list]

It is pulling in all of the degrees [image: list with degrees]

When I enter a field into the field box, say Fireman, it still pulls down ALL of the Degrees options. [image: list with Field]

I want it to autopopulate with the Degree associated with that Field from the Fields and Degrees Test List.[image: Field with Degree only]

Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: You might have to change the way to entered your data, but if you have a look at this [link](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) you can find a solution for "depended lookups" which sounds to me like excately what you're trying to do.

Comment: I followed your link and did a search for "depended lookups" as you suggested, but it comes up with 0 entries.

Comment: I'm Sorry Lauren, but the search term is cascding dropdown and [this](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) is the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What you should look for is Cascading filters sharepoint and infopath.

Cascading filters is the most common term to describe what you want.

This page explains it very well as well as the video

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/05/25/sharepoint-how-to-create-multiple-cascade-drop-downs-using-infopath-2010-aspx/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HnLhXVQf-M

Apologies for not writing the whole tutorial, as you can see it is quite long.

Comment: Thank you Susan.  I followed this video up to 3:35 when he started talking about InfoPath.  Unfortunately I can't use InfoPath.  Do you know how to do it without using InfoPath?  I know it can be done, because I've been told it used to work, and we've never had InfoPath.  Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible without Infopath because the latter allows you to link together the 2 lists in the way you want them to. I guess you could do the same with SharePoint Designer but you need to know how to code and it is a lot harder than what you see in the video done with infopath. Infopath is free and does not damage the platform.

Comment: Thank you.  We had it working previously, but it's possible that the person that established it did something with the code (he seemingly did everything to make this site as complicated and far from out-of-the box as  he possibly could before he handed it over).  I've been trying to push InfoPath (in all my jobs), but have been told it's not a possibility right now due to cost (we have maybe 50 employees that would need it).  Thanks.

Comment: Lauren, check better because Infopath is free if you have volume license for Office Professional.

Comment: I think for some reason we don't. :(  I'll use this post as backing to promote us getting it.  Thanks.